# Embed controls 8 #table element?

Tags: forms, 8

I'm using the Drupal 8 #table element to populate a table on my form, and it's working great for displaying static data.

```
foreach ($entries = getData() as $entry) {
  $row = array_map('Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup::checkPlain', $entry);
  $rows[] = $row;
}
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $headers,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#attributes' => array('id' => 'my-module-list'),
  '#empty' => t('No entries available.'),
);
```

However, I would like to embed a control in each row of the table, for example:

```
foreach ($entries = getData() as $entry) {
  $row = array_map('Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup::checkPlain', $entry);
  $row["field_name"] = array(
    '#type' => 'textbox',
  );
  $rows[] = $row;
}
//dpm($rows);
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => $headers,
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#attributes' => array('id' => 'my-module-list'),
  '#empty' => t('No entries available.'),
);
```

However, the #textbox field is currently being ignored, and an empty cell is shown in its place.

Is there a way I can embed fields in a Drupal generated table, or do I need to build my own table from scratch?

Comment: a) do not use #rows in form. Each child element of #table element is a row and each child element of that row is a table cell. b) #textbox does not exist in Drupal core. Maybe you mean #textfield?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
a) The function getData reads a database table and returns an array of objects. The array_map converts the object into an array of safely marked up data, so $rows is an array of arrays.
b) My mistake. I've tried several element types, but they just become attributes of the td tag. For example "<td #type="textfield"></td>". My suspicion is that embedding form controls in the table isn't supported.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now. The `#rows` element gets converted into a table of plain text cells when the table is rendered. To put controls in the table, put the rows as direct elements of the `#table` array. Everything in the table then gets treated as a control, so plain text cells have to have a `#markup` entry.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is no problem to put form elements in a table. See the example in core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/Table.php:

```
$form['contacts'] = array(
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#title' => 'Sample Table',
    '#header' => array('Name', 'Phone'),
  );

  for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
    $form['contacts'][$i]['name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Name'),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    );

    $form['contacts'][$i]['phone'] = array(
      '#type' => 'tel',
      '#title' => t('Phone'),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    );
  }
```

Maybe you should start from here and then put step by step your code in this example and see when it breaks.

Comment: That's just what I needed.