# How to render a form with 2 fields for each line?

Tags: theming, forms

I'm looking for a way to render a form with 2 text-fields in to the same (for each) line. I would like to do this using hook functions, so I tried with this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'form_page_1') {
    $form['#type'] = 'table';
  }
}
```

But obviously it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You have to place the form elements in the table, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185032/embed-controls-8-table-element

Comment: Why not use CSS?

Comment: `if ($form_id = 'form'page'1') {` is wrong. It needs to be `if ($form_id == 'form'page'1') {`. Next thing `'form'page'1'` is wrong. It probably needs to be `'form_page_1'` or something else.

Comment: @leymannx sorry it is not a copy and paste of the original code

Comment: It should be the exact code so people can assist.

Comment: @Kevin i changed the formid and the module name, so this piece of code is very similar to the original one

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add wrapper to each field with bootstrap classes to both form elements?

```
    $form['field_1_wrapper'] = array(
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('col-sm-6')),
    );

     $form['field_1_wrapper']['field_1'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Field 1'),
    );

    $form['field_2_wrapper'] = array(
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('col-sm-6')),
    );

    $form['field_2_wrapper']['field_2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Field 2'),
    );
```

Comment: I don't have access to the form src; i can modify only ".module" and "css" files