# Adding a submit button in a themed table doesn't work

Tags: forms

When I add a button inside the '#rows' key of a table element, the submit function is not called.

```
class MyForm extends FormBase
{

   public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $my_button = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t("Click"),
            '#submit' => [
                '::custom_submitForm'
            ]
        ];
        $form['my_table'] = [
           // '#tree' => TRUE,
            '#theme' => 'table',
            '#header' => [
                'Column 1','Column 2'
            ],
            '#rows' => [
                [$this->t("Blabla"), ['data'=>$my_button]]
            ],
        ];
        return $form;
    }
    // other stuff
```

What is the best workaround for this?

**EDIT TO ADD:**

As a first try to understand what is going out, I have allowed the children function to consider `'#rows'` as children (see   `Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children`)

```
  public static function children(array &$elements, $sort = FALSE) {
     ...
    foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
      if (is_int($key) || $key === '' || ($key[0] !== '#' || $key=='#rows')) {
     ...
```

This is solving the issue (the handler is called), but of course, this change generate many other problems.. But now, we can understand why the submit handler was not called.

I have added an issue in the drupal queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3166899

I am not asking to correct this bug, but what would be the best workaround.

Comment: if you do `$form['my_button'] = [ ...` it get called? <-- it should, move into an empty row with CSS.

Comment: yes it works... Your solution is to create a table inside `buildForm()` by adding the raw html code in the `"#prefix"=>'<td>'`/`'#suffix'=></td>` of each table element? This is what I was yhinking too... but waiting other ideas

Comment: It wasn't, but that sounds more clever.

Comment: ;-) thank you...

Comment: I've a custom module with a lot of submit buttons in a table. My workaround was to create the structure like `$form['mytable'] = ['#type' => 'container', '#prefix', '<table>', '#suffix' => '</table>'`and then add rows, cells and buttons as children. I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/hudri/4cb05bd631ef53fa28ca80341f73b8da) of my form, the code is old, not a real beauty and not really maintained, but AFAIK it still works in D8.9

Comment: The gist also has some code dealing with detecting the correct trigger button, which you most likely will need when using button per table row.

Comment: Use `'#type' => 'table'` and don't use `#rows`. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185032/embed-controls-8-table-element

Comment: This is clearly the right way to go!!!! Many Thanks. If you add your answer, I will credit you, if not, I will add it myself to help other user who may face the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead of #theme a form element #type:

```
'#type' => 'table'
```

The table form element has an extra step for processing when used in a form.

You don't need `'#rows'`. Any array key not starting with `#`, also the index added automatically by appending a row with `[]`, is considered to be a renderable child and displayed as row.